# Why do I hit the 50K query limit on an object with fewer than 12K records?

Tags: apex, query, governorlimits

I'm working with some code in a complex context that may be above my pay grade (admin who knows enough code to be dangerous). The code below is throwing a 50K query limit exception, even though the object involved has fewer than 12K records.

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults= [SELECT
                 SUM(Number_of_Items__c)Number_of_Items__c,
                 SUM(Number_of_People__c)Number_of_People__c,
                 SR_Object1__r.Campaign__c
             FROM SR_Object2__c 
             WHERE Result_Approved__c = True
             GROUP BY Object1.Campaign__c];
```

This is located in a trigger helper class which is called by a trigger (before insert, before update, after insert, after update) on "Object2" where a large number of records are regularly added or updated at once. I suspect that the heart of the problem may be in that, but before I dive into it, I'm hoping to get an idea of when it might happen that the query limit is hit when the object itself has fewer than 50K records. All the implicated code has been working well until recently.

Comment: Check a debug log to see if there are other queries in the same transaction.

Answer (score 1):

There are some [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm) in Salesforce. These limits help ensure fair access to resources for all subscribers. It's important to note that these limits are per transaction. They cumulatively add up as the transaction occurs, and throw an exception if these limits are violated. In other words, your query might only be looking at 12k records, but if this query runs five times in the same transaction, you've now used 60k of your 50k limit.

A transaction starts when a request is made, and ends with the request ends. For example, if you edit a record in the UI, a transaction starts, and when the UI says the record was successfully saved, the transaction ends. All of the triggers and synchronous automations in the org for that record happen in a single transaction. I usually describe this as "one transaction is one debug log."

As Phil says, this query might not be the culprit. It may be contributing to the problem, but the problem needs a wider view. I usually set up a profiling trace flag, which will include a summary of the number of times a query was called. This can be a helpful indicator of where to look for a query problem. Open the [Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_dev_console.htm&language=en_US&type=5), click on Debug, Change Log Levels..., Add/Change, Add. In the new row, call it Profiling, set all levels to their minimum (NONE), except for Profiling, which you can set to FINEST. Click on each Done button to close the dialogs.

Now, with the Developer Console still open, try your transaction again. You'll get a log file in the Logs tab. Open this log and you'll have a summary near the bottom about how many queries were executed. This will help narrow your search to see which queries or code might need to be optimized. Also, keep in mind that aggregate functions, like SUM, count every individual record that was used to calculate the result. You should add a where clause, if possible, to keep the row count as low as possible.

Comment: IIRC aggregate queries don't support LIMIT, so the "limit" here would be in ensuring there are appropriate WHERE clauses, right?

Comment: @PhilW You're right, I meant to say where, lol.

Comment: Thank you, @sfdcfox. Ya, I was afraid it was due to cumulative calls but didn't know how to troubleshoot that. Your explanation of using trace flags is extremely helpful for that.